# Lambda Expression for Query to select different values based on condition

Tags: c#, lambda

I am working with lambda expression in c#. I am trying to select a value based on type and then the resultant is summed.

```
var  length = (from al in tmp
                from n in al
                 where n.TripPath.DataType =="type1" || n.tripPath.DataType == "Type2"
                 select n.trippath.length).sum();
```

this works fine  but my issue is i need to set vales for other types to a defalute value 0 before it is summed, similar to

```
   List<double> ActualLength = new List<double>();

   if( n.TripPath.DataType =="type1" || n.tripPath.DataType == "Type2")
       ActualLength.Add(n.trippath.length)
   else
       ActualLength.Add(0);

   return ActualLength.sum();
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language or tool it's about. Nobody that knows C# and is looking at the C# tag would know this question existed.

Comment: Why do you need to set it to 0? If the where filters them, they are excluded from the select and not included in the sum. This would have the same effect as setting it to 0.

Comment: Pieter is right. The additional point is that `Enumerable.Empty<int>().Sum()` or similar is `0`. These 2 points make the additional filter redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
var projection =
    tmp.SelectMany(x => x)
       .Select(x => {
           if(x.TripPath.DataType == "type1" || x.TripPath.DataType == "type2") {
               return new { Item = x, Length = x.TripPath.Length };
           }
           else {
               return new { Item = x, Length = 0 };
           }
       });
```

Then you can say

```
int length = projection.Sum(x => x.Length);
```

That is how you can accomplish what it seems like you are trying to do (project each item matching a predicate to its length and otherwise project it to zero).

However, your usage looks like you aren't even using the projections. In which case, you can get away with

```
return tmp.SelectMany(x => x)
          .Where(x => 
              x.TripPath.DataType == "type1" ||
              x.TripPath.DataType == "type2"
          )
          .Sum(x => x.TripPath.Length);
```

Items that don't match the predicate don't hit the sequence that is summed over and therefore they don't contribute anything to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary condition like that:

```
List<double> ActualLength = new List<double>();
var TotalActualLength =  ActualLength.sum(n=> n.TripPath.DataType =="type1" || n.tripPath.DataType == "Type2" ? n.trippath.length : 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the OfType extension method.  You can then project into an anonymous type to assign a default value and .Sum off this.